# Move x axis to top of graph and flip y axis geom_tile

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to rearrange my geom_tile graph. I want to move the x-axis to the top of the graph and then flip the y axis so that the first comparison in the very top left corner of the graph is comparing a-to-a. Right the a-to-a comparison is in the bottom left side of the graph. I am having two problems, when I try to do `position = top`, the x-axis labels go away. I also can seem to figure out how to flip the y-axis. Whenever I try to rearrange the data, only the y-axis labels move and not the data.

Here is the code that I am using

```
ggplot(heat, aes(SNP2, SNP1)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = Score, width=.95, height=.95), colour = "white") + 
  geom_text(aes(label=Score)) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "white", high = "red") +
  labs(x = "",y = "") +
  scale_y_discrete(
  ) +
  scale_x_discrete(
    expand = expansion(mult = c(0,0)), guide = guide_axis(angle = 45)
  ) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    axis.ticks.y = element_line(color = NA),
    axis.ticks.x = element_line(color = NA),
    legend.title=element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_rect(colour = "white", fill=NA, size=1),
    plot.background = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x.top = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y.right = element_blank(),
    legend.key.height= unit(3.5, 'cm'),
    legend.key.width= unit(0.5, 'cm')
  )
```

Here is an example of the data

```
heat <- structure(list(SNP1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L), .Label = c("a", 
"b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", 
"o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u"), class = "factor"), SNP2 = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
21L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
20L, 21L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
19L, 20L, 21L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 
17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
21L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
20L, 21L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
19L, 20L, 21L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", 
"h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", 
"u"), class = "factor"), Score = c(100L, 43L, 40L, 29L, 29L, 
38L, 38L, 33L, 21L, 16L, 15L, 22L, 16L, 25L, 26L, 22L, 21L, 25L, 
20L, 11L, 23L, 43L, 100L, 44L, 34L, 43L, 35L, 38L, 31L, 23L, 
15L, 15L, 16L, 13L, 26L, 28L, 19L, 14L, 17L, 28L, 10L, 24L, 49L, 
53L, 100L, 39L, 33L, 32L, 43L, 29L, 29L, 12L, 12L, 25L, 17L, 
26L, 22L, 18L, 17L, 18L, 32L, 12L, 24L, 35L, 41L, 39L, 100L, 
21L, 31L, 27L, 21L, 30L, 14L, 14L, 23L, 17L, 23L, 21L, 20L, 18L, 
13L, 20L, 13L, 21L, 36L, 53L, 34L, 21L, 100L, 31L, 27L, 33L, 
29L, 21L, 20L, 20L, 23L, 20L, 26L, 21L, 9L, 27L, 21L, 19L, 21L, 
48L, 43L, 33L, 32L, 32L, 100L, 39L, 28L, 29L, 19L, 19L, 22L, 
14L, 22L, 32L, 19L, 10L, 20L, 23L, 12L, 19L, 49L, 49L, 46L, 28L, 
28L, 40L, 100L, 33L, 28L, 15L, 15L, 33L, 10L, 18L, 34L, 19L, 
16L, 13L, 25L, 13L, 21L, 50L, 47L, 36L, 26L, 40L, 33L, 38L, 100L, 
33L, 21L, 21L, 28L, 17L, 29L, 26L, 28L, 24L, 22L, 16L, 14L, 29L, 
33L, 36L, 38L, 38L, 36L, 36L, 35L, 35L, 100L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 
20L, 18L, 29L, 20L, 22L, 20L, 20L, 16L, 20L, 26L, 26L, 17L, 19L, 
28L, 24L, 19L, 22L, 24L, 100L, 96L, 17L, 35L, 9L, 20L, 19L, 11L, 
22L, 15L, 24L, 11L, 25L, 25L, 17L, 19L, 27L, 25L, 19L, 23L, 25L, 
100L, 100L, 17L, 35L, 10L, 21L, 19L, 12L, 21L, 15L, 21L, 12L, 
38L, 28L, 36L, 32L, 28L, 30L, 44L, 32L, 26L, 18L, 18L, 100L, 
14L, 18L, 24L, 30L, 14L, 20L, 18L, 8L, 26L, 29L, 23L, 25L, 25L, 
33L, 21L, 15L, 21L, 23L, 40L, 38L, 15L, 100L, 19L, 8L, 12L, 17L, 
25L, 17L, 25L, 8L, 47L, 47L, 40L, 34L, 30L, 32L, 26L, 36L, 21L, 
11L, 11L, 19L, 19L, 100L, 26L, 19L, 28L, 15L, 23L, 15L, 23L, 
49L, 51L, 34L, 32L, 38L, 47L, 49L, 32L, 34L, 23L, 23L, 26L, 9L, 
26L, 100L, 19L, 15L, 17L, 21L, 9L, 19L, 41L, 35L, 28L, 30L, 33L, 
28L, 28L, 35L, 24L, 22L, 22L, 33L, 13L, 20L, 20L, 100L, 20L, 
15L, 20L, 9L, 26L, 40L, 27L, 27L, 29L, 13L, 16L, 24L, 31L, 27L, 
13L, 13L, 16L, 18L, 29L, 16L, 20L, 100L, 18L, 11L, 18L, 31L, 
49L, 33L, 29L, 20L, 42L, 31L, 20L, 29L, 24L, 27L, 24L, 22L, 27L, 
16L, 18L, 16L, 18L, 100L, 11L, 20L, 11L, 40L, 56L, 53L, 33L, 
35L, 37L, 40L, 21L, 26L, 19L, 19L, 21L, 19L, 26L, 23L, 21L, 12L, 
12L, 100L, 19L, 28L, 23L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 30L, 19L, 21L, 19L, 
21L, 30L, 26L, 9L, 28L, 16L, 9L, 9L, 19L, 21L, 19L, 100L, 14L, 
48L, 50L, 40L, 36L, 36L, 31L, 33L, 40L, 26L, 14L, 14L, 31L, 10L, 
26L, 21L, 29L, 33L, 12L, 29L, 14L, 100L), X = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X.1 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -441L))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `limits = rev` to reverse a discrete y-axis. For the x-axis, `position = "top"` was working, but you had `axis.text.x.top = element_blank()` as theme setting.

```r
library(ggplot2)

# heat <- structure(...) # from OP, omitted for brevity

ggplot(heat, aes(SNP2, SNP1)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = Score, width=.95, height=.95), colour = "white") + 
  geom_text(aes(label=Score)) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "white", high = "red") +
  labs(x = "",y = "") +
  scale_y_discrete(
    limits = rev
  ) +
  scale_x_discrete(
    expand = expansion(mult = c(0,0)), guide = guide_axis(angle = 45),
    position = "top"
  )
```

[image]

Comment: the labels on the top of the x-axis still aren't there. It seems that it has to do with one of the themes that I am using. I want to remove the boarder but I guess that remove the x-axis label on the top of the graph

Comment: yeah I just had to fix `axis.text.x.top = element_blank()`